# IIS Published websites gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, http, asp.net, 500-error

I'm having big trouble publishing my website to IIS. It always returns HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

My project runs perfectly on localhost. I have installed NuGet package MvcDiagnostics.asxp (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/diagnosing-aspnet-mvc-problems.html) to check for any hidden exceptions but I did not found anything.

I am running a Windows Server 2016 where I installed IIS on. I have no database connection needed with my website.

The applicationpool identity is defaulted on ApplicationPoolIdentity and I just added a new website on the 80 port.

I gave the user IIS_IUSRS full permissions on the inetpub folder. My website is added is located under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website

I also tried changing existingResponse="PassThrough" and customErrors mode="Off" in the webconfig but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated! I have been stuck for weeks on this. 
What can I do? Thx!

**SOLUTION**

- Click "Start button"
- in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
- in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
- Click: "World Wide Web Services"
- Click: "Application Development Features"
- Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

It seems I forgot to install some parts of IIS.